# How to get track number in the album?

Tags: android

I am trying to get track number in the album using MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK, it is returning me 1004 for a particular song. But google play music is showing 4 for the same song.

why it is showing different? How to get the number..

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

track contains track number or (cd and track number), look in [docu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.html#TRACK)

here is short example how you can retrieve track number

```
int trackNumber;
int cdNumber;
if(yourTrackString.length() == 4){
     cdNumber = Character.getNumericValue(yourTrackString.charAt(0));
     trackNumber = Integer.parseInt(yourTrackString.substring(1));
 }else{
     cdNumber = 0;
     trackNumber = Integer.parseInt(yourTrackString);
 }
```